# How to use a classname as a predefined variable?

Tags: javascript, class

How can I use a DOM classname to refer to a predefined variable, which has the same name as the className with JavaScript?

For example:

```
<div class="someContent"></div>

//JS
var someContent = "this is a JS variable";

div = document.querySelector(".someContent");

div.innerHTML = div.className;
```

This outputs:

```
<div class="someContent">someContent</div>
```

But I'm trying to output:

```
<div class="someContent">this is a JS variable</div>
```

Using the classname to link to my variable. Is there a way to use the classname to refer to the variable rather than the actual className?

**No jQuery please.**

Here is the fiddle i'm working on http://jsfiddle.net/f6WpJ/

Comment: This looks like an XY problem, you don't want to use the name of the variable, that would be silly, you want to use an object with keys maybe, or an array of classes, or the actual value of the variable.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f6WpJ/1/ but better http://jsfiddle.net/f6WpJ/3/

Comment: Of course, this will fall apart once you have more than one class attached to any particular element; e.g. `<div clas="someContent somethingElse">blah</div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use object and store values inside object:

```
var data = {someContent : "this is a JS variable"};

div = document.querySelector(".someContent");

div.innerHTML = data[div.className];
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6WpJ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is effectively abusing the semantics of element classes; to store data references you will be better off storing them as data attributes, e.g.:

```
<div class="someContent somethingElse" data-param="someContent"></div>
```

That way you decouple the data from any particular class list an element may have.

The code would then look like this:

```
var dataMap = {
    someContent: "this is a JS variable"
};

div = document.querySelector(".someContent");

div.innerHTML = dataMap[div.getAttribute('data-param')];
```

If the browser supports [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) you can do:

```
div.innerHTML = dataMap[div.dataset.param];
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6WpJ/6/)

Comment: That's true, it's probably a lot more future proof as well

Comment: You could use dataSet as well no?

Comment: @user3143218 Oh, definitely ... added as a note.

Comment: Thanks Jack. Appreciate your help buddy

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
var someContent = "this is a JS variable";

div = document.querySelector(".someContent");

div.innerHTML = window[div.className];
```

demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6WpJ/5/)
but there are better ways to do it as suggested by **@dfsq**

**Note**:: usage of `window[div.className]` assumes the variable is in **global scope**

Comment: This assumes that `someContent` is declared globally.